# JSlider hidding Value for GTK+ and Nimbus LookAndFeel On Linux

Tags: linux, gtk, look-and-feel, jslider, nimbus

I have this situation (JSlider Showing Values when is not required). And I don't want to show the current Value on JSlider.

1. **Why only on Linux is shown the value in JSlider using LookAndFeel Nimbus and GTK+?**
2. **How Can I to hide this value?**

The next images shown running the code on Windows 10, Cent OS 7, and MacOS Sierra

[image]

[image]

Here my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JSliderLAF {

  public static void changeLAF(Container container, String laf) {
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | 
        IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    }
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(container);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JPanel jpVert = new JPanel();
      jpVert.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpVert, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        JSlider jsl = new JSlider();
        jsl.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
        jsl.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        jsl.setPaintLabels(true);
        jsl.setPaintTicks(true);
        jsl.setSnapToTicks(true);
        JPanel jpHorz = new JPanel();
        jpHorz.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpHorz, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JLabel jlName = new JLabel(info.getName() + " : ");
        JLabel jlClass = new JLabel(info.getClassName());
        jpHorz.add(jsl);
        jpHorz.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
        jpHorz.add(jlName);
        jpHorz.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2,0)));
        jpHorz.add(jlClass);
        jpHorz.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2,0)));
        jpHorz.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        changeLAF(jsl,info.getClassName());
        jpVert.add(jpHorz);
      }
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.add(jpVert, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }        
}
```

Comment: The answer to the first question is because GTK+ does that by default. I do not know the answer to the second question, alas. I do know that with an actual GTK+ slider [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html#gtk-scale-set-draw-value) is the method (which is also exposed through the `draw-value` GObject property) that will do the trick.

Comment: Thankyou, but Nimbus? Nimbus too is presenting this value.

Comment: If you look carefully the Nimbus sliders look identical to the GTK+ sliders. I'm assuming Nimbus is just using GTK+ with custom styles on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void changeLAF(Container container, String laf) {
  try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
    UIManager.put("Slider.paintValue", false);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | 
      IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
  }
  SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(container);
}
```